# group users by last sent/received message

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a tbl:

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists tblA
(
id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment ,
sender varchar(255),
receiver varchar(255),
 msg varchar(255),
 date timestamp,
  idmsg int(11)  ,
name varchar(255),
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);




INSERT INTO tblA (sender, receiver,msg,date,name,idmsg ) VALUES
('1', '2', 'buzz ...','2011-08-21 14:11:09','Bb','1'),
('1', '2', 'test ...','2011-08-21 14:12:19','Bb','2'),
('1', '2', 'check ...','2011-08-21 14:13:29','Bb','3'),
('1', '1', 'test2 ...','2011-08-21 14:14:09','Aa','4'),
('2', '1', 'check2 ...','2011-08-21 14:15:09','Bb','5'),
('2', '1', 'test3 ...','2011-08-21 14:16:09','Bb','6'),
('1', '2', 'buzz ...','2011-08-21 14:17:09','Bb','7'),
('1', '2', 'test ...','2011-08-21 14:18:19','Bb','8'),
('1', '2', 'check ...','2011-08-21 14:19:29','Bb','9'),
('1', '1', 'test2 ...','2011-08-21 14:10:09','Aa','10'),
('3', '1', 'check2 ...','2011-08-21 14:21:09','Cc','11'),
('3', '1', 'test3 ...','2011-08-21 14:22:09','Cc','12'),
('1', '3', 'check ...','2011-08-21 14:26:29','Cc','13'),
('1', '3', 'test2 ...','2011-08-21 14:27:09','Cc','14'),
('1', '2', 'check3 ...','2011-08-21 14:23:09','Bb','15'),
('1', '4', 'test2 ...','2011-08-21 14:27:09','Dd','16'),
('1', '5', 'test2 ...','2011-08-21 14:27:09','Ee','17'),
('1', '7', 'test3 ...','2011-08-21 14:29:09','Gg','18');
```

How to get distinct group with sender, receiver if 1,2  is same as 2,1 with max(date). I have tried http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b04cd5/29 but I am not getting the exact grouping.

I get 14:11:+09 for 1,2 or 2,1 combo but the right answer is 14:23. Also it's not checking for reverse like its checking for 1,2 but not for 2,1. How Do I fix this?

Comment: Post your desired results.

Comment: The same results as in sql fiddle contains but the values should be accurate.Similar to sms inbox .

Comment: Add to `WHERE`: `AND sender < receiver` for "1,2 but not for 2,1"

Comment: @Alexander can you please correct it on SQL fiddle.

Comment: @jason [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b04cd5/32/0). But, honestly, I'm not sure this is what you wanted, because it still not clear to me what do you want...

Comment: @Alexander no this does not change anything in fact 1 row is lost.But why I am not getting max(date) after grouping ?

Comment: @jason you haven't asked for it in your select statement, you only grouping by max(date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want the latest communication between two people.  I think this does what you want:

```
select least(receiver, sender), greatest(receiver, sender),
       max(date),
       substring_index(group_concat(msg order by date separator '|'), '|', 1) as msg,
       substring_index(group_concat(idmsg order by date), ',', 1) as idmsg,
       substring_index(group_concat(name order by date separator '|'), '|', 1) as name
from tblA 
where '1' in (Receiver, Sender)
group by least(receiver, sender), greatest(receiver, sender);
```

Comment: Thank You Sir .The latest communication between 2 people.Thats it.Sir how do I do with the one you previously showed http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed676/1 .I am getting the old date and not max(date) in this too.Thanks again Sir .Really appreciate your time and effort.Thanks

Comment: Hello Sir .Can you please look into this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21357524/select-the-latest-message-between-the-communication-of-two-users-and-group-them .Thank you Sir .Sorry for the trouble.Thanks again.

Comment: Sir can you please look into this .its the same question with the previous table.Unable to group them  ::::::http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21357524/select-the-latest-message-between-the-communication-of-two-users-and-group-them