# Select the Latest Message Between the communication of two users and group them

Tags: mysql, sql

User no=1 which is `Aa`  :

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists tblA
(
id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment ,
sender varchar(255),
receiver varchar(255),
 msg varchar(255),
 date timestamp,
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE if not exists tblB
(
id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment ,
sno varchar(255),
name varchar(255),
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


INSERT INTO tblA (sender, receiver,msg,date ) VALUES
('1', '2', 'buzz ...','2011-08-21 14:11:09'),
('1', '2', 'test ...','2011-08-21 14:12:19'),
('1', '2', 'check ...','2011-08-21 14:13:29'),
('1', '1', 'test2 ...','2011-08-21 14:14:09'),
('2', '1', 'check2 ...','2011-08-21 14:15:09'),
('2', '1', 'test3 ...','2011-08-21 14:16:09'),
('1', '2', 'buzz ...','2011-08-21 14:17:09'),
('1', '2', 'test ...','2011-08-21 14:18:19'),
('1', '2', 'check ...','2011-08-21 15:19:29'),
('1', '1', 'test2 ...','2011-08-21 14:10:09'),
('3', '1', 'check2 ...','2011-08-21 14:21:09'),
('3', '1', 'test3 ...','2011-08-21 14:22:09'),
('3', '2', 'buzz ...','2011-08-21 14:24:09'),
('3', '2', 'test ...','2011-08-21 14:25:19'),
('1', '3', 'check ...','2011-08-21 14:26:29'),
('1', '3', 'test2 ...','2011-08-21 14:27:09'),
('2', '3', 'check2 ...','2011-08-21 14:28:09'),
('2', '3', 'test3 ...','2011-08-21 14:29:09'),
('1', '2', 'check3 ...','2011-08-21 14:23:09'),
('1', '4', 'test2 ...','2011-08-21 14:27:09'),
('1', '5', 'test2 ...','2011-08-21 14:27:09'),
('2', '6', 'check2 ...','2011-08-21 14:28:09'),
('1', '7', 'test3 ...','2011-08-21 14:29:09'),
('8', '2', 'check3 ...','2011-08-21 14:23:09');


INSERT INTO tblB (sno, name ) VALUES
('1', 'Aa'),
('2', 'Bb'),
('3', 'Cc'),
('4', 'Dd'),
('5', 'Ee'),
('6', 'Ff'),
('7', 'Gg'),
('8', 'Hh');
```

How to get latest communication time b/n 2 users .
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed676/1  the query is not giving latest times of communication.

I really appreciate any help.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Here's a hint.  The combination of "limit" and "order by" will give you what you want.

Comment: Please post the desired result based on your sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select b.name, max(date)
from tblA a join
     tblB b
     on b.sno in (a.receiver, a.sender)
where b.sno <> '1' and 
      exists (select 1
              from tblB b2
              where b2.sno = '1' and
                    b2.sno in (a.receiver, a.sender)
             ) or
      (a.sender = 1 and a.receiver = 1)
group by b.name
order by max(date) desc;
```

This returns the latest time of communication for each "other person" talking to `1`.  Your original query didn't put `max(date)` in the select list.

Comment: Thank you for your response but its not considering 1 - 1 .Can you please look into it.Thanks

Comment: you had sent this before `select least(receiver, sender), greatest(receiver, sender), max(date), substring_index(group_concat(msg order by date separator '|'), '|', 1) as msg, substring_index(group_concat(idmsg order by date), ',', 1) as idmsg, substring_index(group_concat(name order by date separator '|'), '|', 1) as name from tblA where '1' in (Receiver, Sender) group by least(receiver, sender), greatest(receiver, sender);` but its on same table.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to use a `UNION` such as:

```
select * from (
  select * from tblA
  where sender = '1' and receiver = '2'
  union
  select * from tblA
  where sender = '2' and receiver = '1'
) as t
order by date desc
limit 5
```

You can do a few things to make this more efficient such as pushing down some of the limits and ordering into each part of the `UNION`, but this is the basic idea.

Comment: something on these lines: `select least(receiver, sender), greatest(receiver, sender),
       max(date),
       substring_index(group_concat(msg order by date separator '|'), '|', 1) as msg,
       substring_index(group_concat(idmsg order by date), ',', 1) as idmsg,
       substring_index(group_concat(name order by date separator '|'), '|', 1) as name
from tblA 
where '1' in (Receiver, Sender)
group by least(receiver, sender), greatest(receiver, sender);`

Comment: @jason I don't get why/what your proposing. My query above works and I believe does what the asker is looking for.

Comment: I am looking at grouping all users not just 1,2.

Comment: @jason Oh, sorry, didn't notice you were the asker at first. :) OK, maybe redefine: You're looking to get the latest message in either direction for each pair of users?

Comment: `UNION` is not required here, since you can get the same result with `OR` in your `WHERE` clause, and traverse the table only once.

Comment: @PM77-1 Sorry, I should have been a bit more specific but was on my way out and posted a solution. Using `UNION` can be very good because it can make the most efficient use of indexes (if you push any other conditions + `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` into each half of the `UNION`). However this doesn't appear to be what @jason was asking for anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the discussion on my previous answer, I think what you want is something like this:

```
SELECT
  tblA.id,
  sender.name AS sender_name,
  receiver.name AS receiver_name,
  tblA.msg,
  tblA.date
FROM (
  SELECT
    LEAST(sender, receiver) AS a,
    GREATEST(sender, receiver) AS b,
    MAX(id) AS id
  FROM tblA
  GROUP BY a, b
) AS t
JOIN tblA ON t.id = tblA.id
JOIN tblB AS sender ON tblA.sender = sender.sno
JOIN tblB AS receiver ON tblA.receiver = receiver.sno
```

So the basic idea is:

1. Choose the latest message `id`, `auto_increment` or some other form of continuously incrementing numeric `PRIMARY KEY` is assumed for the messages (`tblA`) table. This finds the IDs of those messages without regard to `sender` or `receiver` ordering.
2. Based on the message `id` for each message, select its full detail.
3. Join the message rows against the user (`tblB`) records twice, once to get `sender` details, and once for `receiver` details.

Comment: this is the value I am getting  `19  Aa  Bb  check3 ...  August, 21 2011 14:23:09+0000` which is wrong as the correct value is 15:19

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
select p1.name,p2.name,max(date) from
(select least(sender,receiver) min_val,greatest(sender,receiver) max_val,msg,date from tblA
order by min_val,max_val,date) t inner join tblB p1 on t.min_val=p1.sno
inner join tblB p2 on t.max_val=p2.sno
group by min_val,max_val;
```